# Storing a pointer to the address of a local variable in C side effects

Tags: c

Let's say we have the following code. st is a global stack and is initialized properly. We call foo()

```
struct stack *st;

int foo() {
    int x = 1;
    stack_push(st, &x);
}
```

Now, the stack contains a pointer to x. After foo goes out of scope, what happens to the address &x? Is it deallocated? Can we trust that when we pop() the stack later on and dereferenced it that the value will be 1?

edit: Here's what I'm currently thinking. Since x is allocated on the stack, once it goes out of scope, the memory occupied in address &x can be used by anyone therefore the dereferenced value returned by pop() later on can possibly be not 1.

Comment: It is undefined behavior. It could spawn a chorus line of New York sewer rats in your basement for all you know.

Comment: Please put some minimal effort into the search engine of this site. This question is asked at least 3 times per day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior at the point `foo` returns is undefined.  Often the value will be maintained until the next method call creates a large enough stack to over write it.  But depending on this is wrong and shouldn't be done.

If you need `x` to live longer than `foo` then you need to allocate memory for it on the heap

Comment: thanks. That's what I was thinking as well, I just had to make sure. I have to wait 10 more minutes to accept this.

Answer (score 0):

The global stack hold the pointer pointing to x all the time until global stack is destroyed. But after foo goes out of scope, the stack space occupied by x before could be reused. May be caused by foo() re-entered, or by other function invocation, or any other stack space allocation.